# Throwing errors inside catch blocks allowed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I've come up with the following piece of code of submitting my form to Firebase using async-await with try-catch blocks.

Basically throwing the errors back to the `onSubmit` function that sets the firebaseError when an error has been thrown somewhere. Only when there was no error thrown, the user gets forwarded to the `/posts` authenticated page.

Is throwing the errors back correct or or is there a better option?

```
const [firebaseError, setFirebaseError] = useState(null)

  // Add user to Firestore
  const createUser = async (user) => {
    try {
      await db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set(user)
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }

  // Authenticate user
  const signUp = async ({ email, password }: LoginData) => {
    try {
      const userAuth = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      const userDb = await createUser({ uid: userAuth.user.uid, email })
      return userAuth
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }

  // Callback for handleSubmit
  const onSubmit = async (data: LoginData) => {
    try {
      const user = await signUp(data)
      router.push('/posts')
    } catch (error) {
      setFirebaseError(error.message)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing

```js
try {
      await db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set(user)
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
```

Is redundant. This will just do the same

```js
await db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set(user)
```

as `catch` just gets called when an error is thrown inside the `try` block, throwing it back is just the same as just letting it throw from the firestore async call and then catching it on the parent function `(onSubmit)`.

Normally you would want to use catch when you want to do something rather than throwing the error, such as logging it to some observability platform, or setting some state besides/instead of throwing it.

In fact, `sonarlint` has a rule flagging this: https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/tag/unused/RSPEC-2737

`A catch clause that only rethrows the caught exception has the same effect as omitting the catch altogether and letting it bubble up automatically, but with more code and the additional detriment of leaving maintainers scratching their heads. Such clauses should either be eliminated or populated with the appropriate logic.`

Answer (score 1):

Can't see anything wrong with the way you're handling exceptions, basically when someone signs up you try to create a user and if everything went fine you redirect to /posts, and if any exceptions are being thrown in the end you catch it.

Only thing that I would personally add would be some user notification based upon the error if you have't already done in other parts of your code, and maybe even more important checking where the error happen, so you can do a cleanup, let's say

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

succeeded but the creating the user in the DB fails, in the catch block you should first try to clear the new created user and then throw the error.